# Get Child Category only

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy

I am using this code to retrieve category:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
  $countries = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'country' );
  $fcountry = $countries[0]->slug;
```

However this sometimes retrieves the parent category of the countries (in our scenario the continent). How could I make this to always output the child category (i.e. the country)?

Comment: In the cases where it is wrong, did you do something like `var_dump($countries);` to see if the correct one is in there? Because you've hardcoded it to always take the first category from the result set, this may be wrong

Comment: Yes this is my question, ideally I would like to define parent and child in separate variables. There is always going to be 1 parent for each child.

Comment: Can a post have multiple parent & child categories? Or will there always be only 1 child ever (and 1 parent)?

Comment: only 1 child and 1 parent (continent/country) - this is a custom taxonomy as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, the problem here is that `get_the_terms(..)` returns both the parent and child category. As you said in the comment, there will only ever be 1 parent and 1 child in it, we can use that information to get the correct term.

Basically we need to filter the results, we know that one will have `parent` not set while the other has it, so just get the latter one.

```
function joamika_get_country_from_post(int $postId): ?string {
    $countries = get_the_terms($postId, 'country');
    if (!is_array($countries)) {
        return null;
    }
    array_filter($countries, function(\WP_Term $term): bool {
        return $term->parent !== 0;
    });
    if (empty($countries)) {
        return null;
    }
    return $countries[0]->slug;
}

$fcountry = joamika_get_country_from_post($post_id);
if ($fcountry === null) {
    // something went wrong
}

// continue with your logic
```

If this is your first time seeing something like `foo(int $postId): ?string {`, don't worry. You can remove them or keep them. I prefer my PHP code to be as strictly typed as possible - you can [read more about the topic here](https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.declarations.php).

You still need to think about handling the case when no country is found.

Comment: I will give this a shot but are the if functions nested correctly? seems that if sth goes wrong $fcountry will still get defined

Comment: @JoaMika they are correct in the sense that this should give you a base to work with. You'd probably want to put all of this in a function that returns a string, and work your application's logic around that. So the `// something went wrong` blocks would `return '';` and a success returns the slug. Then `$my_slug = get_fcountry_slug( $post_id );` and use that as needed. You'll have to figure out what to do in the case of getting an empty string, since you can't always 100% be sure you'll get something useful back.

Comment: thank you for your help, I will try to create this custom function, though I am not this good :(

Comment: @JoaMika I've put it inside a function. Will add a short description now.

Comment: ok this is very helpful, many thanks :)

Comment: still getting the parent in some instances after testing.. any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: @JoaMika Is the parent also a child of something? Maybe you have it like World > Americas > US?